# anonymous type in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am trying to query a datatable in vb.net. I am getting compile time error "End of statement expected" after first line.

```
Dim query = From p In dt.AsEnumerable() Where p.Field(Of int)("code") = 235 _
    New With { _
        .name = p.Field(Of String)("name"), _
        .age = p.Field(Of Integer)("age") _
        }
```

I am very new to linq and could not figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
Dim query = From p In dt.AsEnumerable() 
            Where p.Field(Of Int32)("code") = 235  
            Select New With { 
               .name = p.Field(Of String)("name"), 
               .age = p.Field(Of Int32)("age") 
            }
```

The `Select` was missing. `int` is also not a type in VB.NET, it is `Int32` or `Integer`.

Note that i have removed the underscores which are unnecessary if you use at least VS 2010.